# Jquery load png image strange characters

Tags: jquery, html, image

Help me please, when load image with jquery Im getting strange charachters like this.

```
�PNG  IHDR���X��sBIT|d� pHYs � �B(�xtEXtSoftwarewww.inkscape.org��< IDATx��wxUE��?�B M: H" *��AE��`})� � ����꺫��kaAw���X@�,]Ŋ��D:�^" $��?�ܛ���$�\r3��'s���=�{��(�b�'*��X�f�@,�@,�@,�@,�@,�@,�@,�@,�@,�@,�@,�@,�@,�@,�@,�@,�@,�@,�@,�@,�@,�@,�@,�@,�@,�@,�@,�@,�@,b�p��J���} �MDN�b�,g�^ @ ��_�T&�=0xVDN�R�,aF�t@)�p����9�r
```

Here is my Jquery code

```
  $("#load").on('click',function(){
        //alert("okk");
        $("#wrapper").load('assets/img/logo.png');

    });
```

What should I do?

Comment: Try not loading an image with xhr...

Comment: and if you do, load it using [FileReader.readAsDataURL()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader/readAsDataURL)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The jQuery `load` method (as seen in the docs http://api.jquery.com/load/) loads data as HTML, which isn't what you want to do. In order to view the PNG as an image, you should add the link as a the `src` attribute to an image tag. So, add an `ìmg` tag inside your `#wrapper` element and alter your jQuery as follows:

```
$("#load").on("click", function() {
    $("#wrapper img").attr("src", "assets/img/logo.png")
});
```